# Property value is not printing on velocity template

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, velocity

I am using Spring with Velocity and I try to print some literal on my velocity template, but it is not working. Here is my template, **exporteComplete.vm:**

```
${savePath}
```

Here is the code:

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ....
    boolean success = processor.exportCourse(courseId, exportPlayer, exportAssets, exportJson);

    ...
    if (success) {
        log.debug("Export Success");
        return new ModelAndView("templateScene/exportComplete");
    } else {
        log.debug("Export Failure");
        return new ModelAndView("templateScene/exportError", "context", context);
    }

}
```

Here is the method:

```
public boolean exportCourse(String courseId, boolean exportPlayer, boolean exportAssets, boolean exportJson) {


    context = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    context.put("savePath", "save path complete");
    VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(engine, "templateScene/exportComplete.vm", "UTF-8", context);

    boolean test = true;

    if (test) {     
        return true;        
    }
}
```

I end up with `${savePath}` result, when view returns **exportComplete.vm**.

Why it is not printing value when view returns?

**EDIT
------------------------------------------------------------**

This is working code.

```
@Override
public ModelAndView handleRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

    ....
    context = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    boolean success = processor.exportCourse(courseId, exportPlayer, exportAssets, exportJson, context);
    if (success) {
        log.debug("Export Success");
        return new ModelAndView("templateScene/exportComplete", "context", context);

    } else {
        log.debug("Export Failure");
        return new ModelAndView("templateScene/exportError", "context", context);
    }

}
```

And here is the method

```
public boolean exportCourse(String courseId, boolean exportPlayer, boolean exportAssets, boolean exportJson, Map<Object, Object> myContext) {

    ...
    if (myContext != null) {

        myContext.put("savePath", "Save Path Complete");
        return true;

    }

}
```

and here is the template

```
${context.savePath}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`savePath` is a property of the `context` `Map` variable.

As the proper way to access it would be `context.get("savePath")`, instead of:

```
${savePath}
```

You should use:

```
${context.savePath}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for explaining, but it is not working. Now the result is  `${context.savePath}` when view returns exportComplete.vm ... . My `exportCourse()` method is in different class, does this matter ?

Comment: Yes, it does matter. The `context` in `exportCourse()` is not the same `context` in `handleRequest()`? Also, `context` would only be available when you return it, that is, the `else` case: `return new ModelAndView("templateScene/exportError", "context", context);`

Comment: Yes you are right :). Can i edit your answer to put the working code, and then i will accept your answer or i edit my post and put the working code there and accept your answer. What do you say ?

Comment: If you edit my answer, the reviewers will reject. Add it to your question after something like "**edit:**" and I will update the answer accordingly for future viewers.

Comment: Thanks :) One thing that i want to ask that it is not necessary to call `VelocityEngineUtils.mergeTemplateIntoString(engine, "templateScene/exportComplete.vm", "UTF-8", context);`. Whatever you put in the context it is automatically render on template. Am i right ?

Comment: Yes! In other words, the template uses the same model as the view.